# Email Message sent out even when Approval Request fails

Tags: email, process-builder, validation-rule, approval-process, emailmessage

We have an Approval Process (AP) and a Process Builder (PB) on `Email Message` object. We also have a PB on `Case` object. The logic is following:

1. A user creates an `Email Message` on a `Case` record and submits this `Email Message` for approval
2. Someone else approves the approval request
3. The AP sends the `Email Message` and sets the `EmailMessage.Status_of_Approval__c` field to `Approved`
4. The PB on `Email Message` is now triggered and it sets the related `Case.Status` field to `Approved`
5. Finally, the PB on `Case` is triggered and it tries to set the `Case.Status` now from `Approved -> Closed`, but it fails due to a Validation Rule

**The outcome:**

The approver receives the error message, however, the Approval Request gets **Approved** and the `Email Message` is already sent out. In addition, the `Case.Status` field remains as it was before the Approval Request was approved (i.e. it's now in an *invalid* state, as the `Status` field doesn't represent what had actually happened).

**The expected behavior:**

I would expect that the Approval Request remains open, and that the `Email Message` is not sent out, especially considering that the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) states that the emails are sent out at the very end of a transaction:

> 20. Commits all DML operations to the database.
> 21. Executes post-commit logic, such as sending email.

It is puzzling that the Approver would receive the Error Message, and that the Approval Request would still be **Approved** and the `Email Message` sent out. Considering that the Approver sees the error, I would think that both the AP and the 2 PBs are part of the same transaction, and as such they should have been rolled back together.

Am I overlooking something, or is this a SF bug?

---

P.S. I understand that PB on step 4 and 5 could probably be merged into one (not sure if this would fix the issue though). This is currently implemented in such a way so that the Field History would clearly show that the `Case.Status` went from `Pending Approval -> Approved -> Closed`, instead of just `Pending Approval -> Closed`.